# How to make Navigation Bar to conform to safe area?

Tags: swift

I moving from a screen without a navigation bar to a screen with a navigation bar.
When going to the navigation bar screen, the bar is not included in any safe area constraints and is overlapping with the status bar on the iPhone X. I looked for a solution but nothing worked for me.
How can I make the navigation bar to conform to safe area guide on the iPhone X so it won't overlap?
also, it's height seems too short, but I guess that would be solved with the constraints.

Thanks in advance!

AppDelegate:

```
var window: UIWindow?
var navigationController: UINavigationController?
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    if let window = window{
        let mainVC = ViewController()
        navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)
        window.rootViewController = navigationController
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    return true
}
```

This is the method I'm using to move from ViewController to AboutViewController:

```
    @objc private func infoButtonTap(){
    let aboutVC = AboutViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(aboutVC, animated: true)
}
```

EDIT: 
This is how it looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONxTb.jpg

AboutVC:

this line is in viewDidLoad:

```
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

to make the navigation bar visible.

Comment: Please ignore this comment if your issue has been solved.

Can you confirm that you are using only the navigationBar associated with the navigationController for display purposes? Or, is there any other custom navigation bar that is being used in your **AboutViewController** class or Interface builder?

Because, everything looks good otherwise, and should not have caused this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to make your navigation controller to be within the safe area. This is one solution for you.

1. Created a UIController as the very base controller of everything. Let's call it `SuperParentController`.
2. Make sure `SuperParentController` also be the parent of your navigation controller.
3. Then you can operate the content and layout for your `SuperParentController` to make sure navigation controller is positioned as you wanted.

We kinda use this strategy to show a universal banner for our app that can be presented any time.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: You are the hero of the day :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything in your sample looks correct. I'm guessing there is some manipulation of the frames happening in either `ViewController` or `AboutViewController`. Look to see when the `window.rootViewController` changes it `frame` or `bounds` to debug what's happening.

Comment: The Navigation Bar is hidden in the ViewController, and I want to show it with the back button in the AboutViewController, So I guess it's changing in the AboutViewController. How can I change it to conform to the safe area guide ?

Comment: @JohnDoah If you don't want to have the look of a navigation controller, then why not use a modal view controller to present About instead of a navigation controller?

Comment: @JohnDoah Could you post the code for hiding and showing the navigation bar and/or the status bar?

Comment: I posted the line to make the bar visible.

Answer (score -1):

Embed the view controller in a navigation controller rather than adding a navigation bar manually. Select the view controller in your storyboard then follow the instructions in the attached screenshot.

[Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfOnb.jpg)

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention I'm not using storyboard. should have mentioned, sorry, I'm now editing the OP.

Comment: Oh, right. No worries. Sorry I'm not sure how to do it without storyboard.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quiet sure what the problem is. Your screenshot refers to landscape mode. This behaviour is intended since iOS8 for landscape. As you included the navigationbar via the corresponding UINavigationController and pushed the next ViewController you are good to go as you are.

UINavigationBar is 44ps but StatusBarFrames differ - you could work with `UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height` to get the actual height of statusbar and add it to you navigationbar-height.

Btw: If you want to respect the sareAreaLayouts for iPhone X, Xs and Xr there is a suitable `NSLayout-Y/X-AxisAnchor` to satisfy your needs.